# Powershell - How to set TCP Send Receive Line End Character? <CR> vs <LF>

Tags: powershell, tcp, streamreader

I was trying to make a little TCP Client Send and Receive script to send actual date to an industrial camera. The device expects `[date]<CR>` as end char, and sends back `OK<CR>` or `ER<CR>` message.

I've found a base script for send here: https://riptutorial.com/powershell/example/18118/tcp-sender

I've added StreamReader function to it, test with Hercules SETUP Utility and it gives back a return message... if the end char is `<LF>`... But I need `<CR>` to send and receive also. [Communication manual, page 527.](https://assets.omron.eu/downloads/manual/en/v3/fhv_series_communications_settings_communications_manual_en.pdf)

```
Function Send-TCPMessage { 
    Param ( 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
            [string] 
            $EndPoint
        , 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
            [int]
            $Port
        , 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
            [string]
            $Message
    ) 
    Process {
        # Setup connection 
        $IP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($EndPoint) 
        $Address = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($IP) 
        $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient($Address,$Port) 
    
        # Setup stream wrtier 
        $Stream = $Socket.GetStream() 
        $Writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($Stream)
        $Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($Stream)

        # Write message to stream
        $Message | % {
            $Writer.WriteLine($_)
            $Writer.Flush()
        }

        $Response = $Reader.ReadLine()

        # Close connection and stream
        $Stream.Close()
        $Socket.Close()

        return $Response
    }
}

$retunMessage = Send-TCPMessage -Port 23 -Endpoint 127.0.0.1 -message "My first TCP message !"
Write-Host "Return Message = " $retunMessage
```

I was trying to test with Hercules SETUP Utility, and Google up the right parameter/setting for modify end character. With no success. Someone could help to identify, what parameters should I set to modify the end char to `<CR>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For *writing* with [`System.IO.StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter), set its `.NewLine` property (before writing to the stream):

  ```
  $Writer.NewLine = "`r"  # CR
  ```
- For *reading* with [`System.IO.StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader),  you'll have to resort to *character-by-character* reading:

  ```
  # Read a line terminated by a single CR
  $lineBuf = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new(80)
  while (($codePoint = $Reader.Read()) -ne -1 -and $codePoint -ne 13) {
    $null = $lineBuf.Append([char] $codePoint)
  }
  $Response = $lineBuf.ToString()
  ```

  - Note:

    - Normally, *no* extra effort is needed if your lines are terminated with CR *only*, because **a line is defined as** (from the `System.IO.StreamReader` reader's [`.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine) docs; emphasis added):

      > a sequence of characters **followed by a carriage return (0x000d), a line feed (0x000a), a carriage return followed by a line feed**, Environment.NewLine, or the end-of-stream marker.

      - In other words: CR alone, LF alone, and CRLF are all recognized as newlines.
    - With ***file* input**, use of **`.ReadLine()` is sufficient**. However, when communicating **with *devices* / intermittent *streams***, the implication is that **`.ReadLine()` doesn't return until either EOF is reached or at least one *additional* character *after* a CR can be read**, because it has to examine that additional character for being a LF, given that a CRLF sequence is a newline too.

      - Thus, to prevent reading a line from possibly blocking indefinitely in your case, the character-by-character reading approach shown above is needed.

Comment: `$Writer.NewLine = "`r"` works well for sending. Thank you! 
What is strange for me: If I send back a message from HERCULES (`$Reader.ReadLine()` in script), it works different with `<CR>` and `<LF>`: If the message (from Hercules Setup Utility) ends with `<LF>`, I got back the `$Response` instantly. But I need 2x `<CR>` to get the same effect. Maybe HERCULES sends data in a different way?

Comment: Good point, @bigbadplayer - I missed that `.ReadLine()` won't return until at least one additional character after the CR is available - please see my update.

Comment: Thank you @mklement0! I tried it with the actual device and the char-by-char buffer method worked perfectly!